# Is an enemy counteroffensive in an optional war a milchemet mitzva?

Tags: army-military-war

After consulting the Urim vThumin, Shlomo decides to conquer Egypt. He captures the Nile Delta.

An Egyptian force from the south moves upward to liberate it. Since the Jews are now on the defensive, does the war transform from an optional war to a mandatory one? Or does this only happen when Eretz Yisrael is on the brink of invasion?

Comment: I suppose the latter. Since the Nile Delta was never part of the original Eretz Yisrael.

Comment: I'd say, that as long as civilian Jews are not under attack, it does not become a _milchemet mitzva_ (of _ezrat Yisra'el mi-tzar she-ba aliehem_). Also, I don't think it should matter whether those civilians are in Eretz Yisrael proper, or in lands conquered in previous optional wars. If civilian Jews are under attack, a king should be able to raise an army to defend them, as needed, without needing the _beit din ha-gadol_ (of 71) to sign off on it.

Comment: Defensive is in chutz laaretz as well. One can fight  preemptively even on shabbos per the Shulchan Aruch 329